# Automatically generate a database schema diff script

Tags: sql-server, tfs, msbuild, database-schema

We are using TFS (service, not server) to manage the versions of our database schema. Periodically TFS generates a build and saves it in a drop folder.

Following best practices (http://martinfowler.com/articles/evodb.html), recommendations, and above all, based in our own experience (and suffering), we want to generate automatically a daily/weekly diff script with the changes checked in.

There are a lot of tools (RedGate, Visual Studio, Open Sourece) that help to do this job, and I've tried all. But in all the cases needs to be done manually.

We are doing as often as we can… but since it is manually it is not as often as it should be necessary ;)

Is there a way to do it automatically (unattended)? Can be done between 2 deployment scripts of builds? Or to do it between 2 databases? Is it also possible to compare data automatically too?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to automatically generate the difference script. We have done that in my company.

We're using vsdbcmd command line tool from Visual Studio to generate the deployment script from the build and later use that script to deploy in the test servers. We do that using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: What about the default data? How do you manage default data like ZIP codes, field descriptions/translations, etc.

Comment: We use scripts do that. Same for any kind of data transformation or migration that we have to do between versions. The upgrade process runs those manual scripts first before comparing the schema.